# The multi-part identifier "Interfaces.Availability" could not be bound

Tags: mysql

1. Trying to query and combined two to three tables but getting could not be bound error

   ```
   SELECT Nodes.Caption AS NodeName 
   ,Interfaces.Caption AS InterfaceName 
   ,AlertActive.Acknowledged 
   ,AlertActive.AcknowledgedDateTime 
   ,AlertActive.TriggeredDateTime 
   FROM Nodes 
   JOIN Interfaces As Interface ON Nodes.NodeID = Interface.NodeID 
   JOIN ActiveAlerts As Objects ON Objects.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID 
       AND Objects.NodeID = Interface.NodeID 
   JOIN AlertActiveObjects AS Alerts ON Alerts.AlertActiveID = Objects.AlertID 
   WHERE Interfaces.Availability = 2
   ```

Comment: SELECT
    Nodes.Caption AS NodeName
    ,Interfaces.Caption AS InterfaceName
    ,AlertActive.Acknowledged
    ,AlertActive.AcknowledgedDateTime
    ,AlertActive.TriggeredDateTime
FROM Nodes
JOIN Interfaces As Interface ON Nodes.NodeID = Interface.NodeID
JOIN ActiveAlerts As Objects ON Objects.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID AND Objects.NodeID = Interface.NodeID
JOIN AlertActiveObjects AS Alerts ON Alerts.AlertActiveID = Objects.AlertID
WHERE Interfaces.Availability = 2

Comment: Above is the query

Comment: are you sure you are using mysql and not sql.server ??'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are mixing table name and alias  table name

```
JOIN Interfaces As Interface  --  WHERE Interfaces.Availability = 2
```

if you use alias  then use it everywhere

```
    SELECT Nodes.Caption AS NodeName 
    ,Interfaces.Caption AS InterfaceName 
    ,AlertActive.Acknowledged 
    ,AlertActive.AcknowledgedDateTime 
    ,AlertActive.TriggeredDateTime 
    FROM Nodes 
    JOIN Interfaces As Interface ON Nodes.NodeID = Interface.NodeID 
    JOIN ActiveAlerts As Objects ON Objects.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID 
        AND Objects.NodeID = Interface.NodeID 
    JOIN AlertActiveObjects AS Alerts ON Alerts.AlertActiveID = Objects.AlertID 
    WHERE Interface.Availability = 2
```